# Why is the -c in "sh -c command" mandatory in some cases, and impermissible in others?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I am using [wait-for](https://github.com/eficode/wait-for/blob/master/wait-for), a linux POSIX (#!bin/sh) script in my docker configuration (`python:3.8.1-alpine3.11`).

In my docker-compose.yml I use the following command to load the script:

```
app:
   command: sh -c "wait-for postgres:5432 && python manage.py migrate 
                && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

However, this results in `/bin/sh: wait-for: not found`. The file is definitely there as I can see it when I shell into the container.

Through trial and error inside the container, I found the following will work:

```
/usr/src/app $  sh wait-for
```

In short, using the `-c` flag appears to cause the option. I understand [`sh -c` calls the program `sh` as the interpeter and executes the script as intrepreted by this command,](https://askubuntu.com/a/831850/177493) but what is happening in this case / why does `-c` cause an issue with the script?

E.g. other commands in the line do not run without `-c`; `sh python` would not run, it requires `sh -c python`.

What's the correct approach to use in my `docker-compose.yml` file? Should I have two command entries (one for `sh wait-for` and another for `sh -c [other commands]`)?

Comment: "not found" can mean that the interpreter (if a script) or a library dependency (if a native executable) is missing. Without knowing what `wait-for` is or how it's built, this isn't answerable.

Comment: Thanks @Charles Duffy. I have updated the question with the `wait-for` code.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?  On the one hand it seems like there are a lot of details in the `Dockerfile` that don't matter to the question; on the other, seeing a fuller excerpt from the `docker-compose.yml` would be useful.  (If you're hiding the image content with `volumes:`, for example, that could readily cause this.)

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks, I have refactored the question. From trial and error the issue seems to be the `-c` flag but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 5):

`sh script.sh` takes a filename, reads commands out of it, and execute those; it specifically executes a shell script.  If the filename doesn't contain a slash, [it searches the current directory before searching `$PATH`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html#tag_20_117_05).  This form always runs a shell script, which is why *e.g.* `sh python` doesn't work.

`sh -c 'command'` takes a single command as a positional argument and executes it.  The various command names there are interpreted according to the normal rules; in particular they must be somewhere in the `$PATH` environment variable, or else have a slash in their names.

In your Dockerfile it looks like you're copying the `wait-for` script into the current directory (with the rest of your application).  So here the `sh wait-for` construct uses the "search the current directory first" rule and works, but the `sh -c 'wait-for ...'` form doesn't find it in `$PATH`.  The easiest workaround is to explicitly qualify the latter invocation with a relative path

```yaml
command: sh -c "./wait-for postgres:5432 && ..."
```

A more broadly useful pattern is to split first-time setup (like "wait for a database" and "run migrations") into an entrypoint script, and have its final step be "run the main container command".  Your entrypoint can be a normal shell script

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e  # stop on error; equivalent to the "&&" in the one-liner
./wait-for "$POSTGRES_HOST:$POSTGRES_PORT"
python manage.py migrate
exec "$@"
```

and then in the Dockerfile you'd separately specify an entrypoint and command

```sh
COPY wait-for entrypoint .
RUN chmod +x wait-for entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint"]
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

and not specify anything in the `docker-compose.yml` at all.